# How to make screen reader finish announcing table column name, pause and then announce supplementary information about the column?

Tags: javascript, html-table, accessibility

We have a table where one of the columns, (and in the future possibly others as well) has an information icon (ℹ️) next to the column name. When you mouse over it, a tooltip appears which reveals additional information about the meaning of the values in the column.

To make the icon interaction accessible we have made it so that when the column header is focused, a hotkey is enabled which triggers the popup. The only issue we have is that we need to announce the hotkey for the column, however using things like `aria-label`, or `aria-describedby` on the icon, (which is inside the column header but is separate to the title) makes screen readers announce it as part of the title of the column.

They read it back something like this:

> metrics press the 'i' key for additional information column header column 8

We would like for it to read the "press the 'i' key for additional information" after a  brief pause after reading out the column information as this text is only really needed the first time a user encounters this particular table and occasionally in the future if the user forgets about the interaction.

I know I can setup something elaborate like having a global `div` with `aria-role="status"` and `aria-live="polite"` and then update the text inside with the announcement we need, but that has the high probability of causing issues down the line when we use similar mechanisms for accessible loading spinners, status updates etc.

I want to know if there's a standard way of accomplishing this as I haven't been able to find anything of relevance myself.

Here's a snippet with just column headers to illustrate the issue.

```css
.row {
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.column-header {
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

c-icon
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div role="grid">
  <div role="rowgroup">
    <div role="row" class="row">
      <div
        class="column-header"
        role="columnheader"
        aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="true"  tabindex="0"
      >
        <span role="presentation">
          ID
        </span>
      </div>
      <div
        class="column-header"
        role="columnheader"
        aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="true"  tabindex="0"
      >
        <span role="presentation">
          Name
        </span>
      </div>
      <div
        class="column-header"
        role="columnheader"
        aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="true"  tabindex="0"
      >
        <span role="presentation">
          Metrics
        </span>
        <c-icon
          aria-label=", Press the 'i' key for additional information"
          role="none"
          style="width: 23px; height: 23px;"
        >
          <svg
            version="1.1"
            class="has-solid"
            viewBox="0 0 36 36" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            focusable="false"
          >
            <path class="clr-i-solid clr-i-solid-path-1"
              d="M18,6A12,12,0,1,0,30,18,12,12,0,0,0,18,6Zm-2,5.15a2,2,0,1,1,2,2A2,2,0,0,1,15.9,11.15ZM23,24a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H15a1,1,0,1,1,0-2h2V17H16a1,1,0,0,1,0-2h4v8h2A1,1,0,0,1,23,24Z">
            </path>
          </svg>
        </c-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Care to put a fiddle together of your current HTML? It will make it a lot easier to advise what is best. You probably don't need to do anything, there is nothing actually wrong with it saying "metrics press the "i" key for additional information" as that is expected behaviour, you have to bear in mind that screen reader users are used to this (and that they often listen at 300% or higher read speed so your pauses are less relevant to them!)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I just updated the question with a snippet which illustrates the issue. I simplified it down to just the column headers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to give the columnheader an `aria-label` attribute that overrides its contents, and an `aria-describedby` attribute that references the icon's label.

I believe this results in screen readers announcing only the columnheader label when traversing the cells in the column, and announcing its label followed by its description when focused.

```html
<div
  class="column-header"
  role="columnheader"
  aria-label="Metrics"
  aria-describedby="column-header-metrics-info-icon"
  aria-readonly="true"
  tabindex="0">
  <span role="presentation">
    Metrics
  </span>
  <c-icon
    role="none"
    id="column-header-metrics-info-icon"
    aria-label="(Press the 'i' key for additional information)"
    style="width: 23px; height: 23px;">
    <svg ... />
  </c-icon>
</div>
```

Be sure to read through the ARIA [Tooltip](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#tooltip) widget [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#tooltip) and [this blog post](https://sarahmhigley.com/writing/tooltips-in-wcag-21/) for guidance.

You can increase discoverability of the keyboard shortcuts by adding the [`aria-keyshortcuts`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-keyshortcuts) attribute. Keyboard shortcuts may not work well with voice control, switch control, screen readers on touch devices, so ensure that the information is also available through some other means.